# I sent my eth to the wrong address

Tags: transfer

Instead of transferring my Eth token to my wallet, I accidentally sent it to the contract address of of the offshift XFT token
0xabe580e7ee158da464b51ee1a83ac0289622e6be

Would the contract creator be able to send it back to me?

Comment: you sent your ether or your xft tokens? because the contract has no ether now? when did you did it und can you show the tx?

Comment: I send ether. It was today february 15th about 12.00 GMT

Comment: @Mario75plhotmailcom Do you have the transaction hash? The contract doesn't have a fallback function so any ether transfer should fail.

Comment: Thank you, everything is ok, the transaction failed and I still have my eth on my coinbase account.